# How to pick a Javascript object randomly by index?

Tags: javascript

I have the following var, which is an object:

```
var users = {};
```

I insert users in this object like this:

```
users["john"] = "johns property";
users["mike"] = "mikes property";
users["luke"] = "lukes property";
```

I've read many questions here, and I've learned that you can't access objects directly by index. Ok, no problem, because I need to pick any random object from this "array of objects" (if that's the right expression).

More specifically, I want to **pick any random object from the collection**, it can be john, mike or luke, whichever. I know I can use a random number generator to get a random index, but then I won't be able to access an object from the collection using the index; so I'm looking for directions.

Comment: Get keys using `Object.keys()`. Get random number from 0 to the `no. of keys - 1`. Get the value of the key at that index in keys.

Comment: `Object.keys(users)` is a starting point ... oops, Tushar beat me to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi try following...

```
var users = {};

users["john"] = "johns property";
users["mike"] = "mikes property";
users["luke"] = "lukes property";

var index = Object.keys(users);

console.log(users[index[Math.floor(Math.random()*index.length)]]);
```